# Getting invalid value in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `sales` and `sales_stg`. The first one is source table and second one is staging table.

> While doing the audit to find out the inconsistency between the above
>   two tables, I am getting amount even though no row exists in staging
>   table.

The DDL, DML statements and audit queries are given in the SQL fiddle 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3333/2

Comment: I don`t understand what you want.What is the staging table?sales_stg?Then why do you say there are no rows in it?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: (unsurprisingly) you're query returns exactly the result that I would expect from the data set provided

Comment: @Mihai You can think one is a production table and another is a staging table. I want to find the out of sync rows between the two tables. Here the row 'insert into sales values(100, 201, "SOUTH");' doesn't flow to staging table. I want to find out those rows.

Answer (score 0):

To find the inconsistent record you can use this query derived from yours

```
select sum(SL.sales_amt) as SALES_SUM, sum(ST.sales_WIP_amt) as SALES_STG_SUM, SL.sales_id, SL.location
from sales SL INNER JOIN sales_stg ST
ON SL.sales_id = ST.sales_id
group by SL.sales_id, SL.location
having SALES_SUM != SALES_STG_SUM
```

If this is not what you want you have to explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Why the value 111.00 is present in  SALES_STG_SUM field? It should be 0.00 correct?

Comment: Ok I got what you mean. You're talking about 100-SOUTH case. As you group by normal db fields and you try to group stg table's fields  this sql is giving you wrong results. You better use


`select sum(ST.sales_amt) as SALES_SUM, ST.sales_id, ST.location
   from sales_stg ST
       group by ST.sales_id, ST.location;`

this will give you the right result.

Comment: Thanks @Sezin Karli In real-time there is a chance like mismatch can happen at more than one fields like location, amount fields. I now understood when to use JOIN, SUB QUERY or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want just the row just simply use a LEFT JOIN with multiple conditions and check for NULL in the second table.

```
   select  SL.sales_id,sales_amt, SL.location
   from sales SL LEFT JOIN sales_stg ST
   ON SL.sales_id = ST.sales_id AND sales_amt=sales_wip_amt
     and SL.location=ST.location
     where sales_wip_amt IS NULL
```

Comment: This is fine. If a row in sales table is having dollar amount of $100 and this information is broken into multiple rows in another table like $50, $30 and $20 (the sales_id alone is same). So I used the sum() function in my query. Is there anyway to fix my select query with adding logic to handle null rows.????

Comment: @Athiruban Than you would JOIN on a subquery with SUM ..GROUP BY for the second table and check on that.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai :) I learnt that it is not good to use JOIN operator for this scenario and we can get the sales_id and location in which there is a problem. I updated the sql fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d6b/1